# Flutter: Question/Answer ListView one item per page (like e.g. Taxfix)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I am relatively new to Flutter and just building a Web App for learning purpose. If someone knows Taxfix, which is by the way amazing!, I am wondering how they did this really nice question and answer design? LookHere Sorry that it is in German, but I hope you get the point.

How could you achieve smth. similar? I guess the Main part is a ListView?! And then just dynamically somehow create new questions out of the answers before? I guess the StateManagement is the key?

To concrete the question, how could I achieve a ListView, showing only one item per page and adds dynamically new questions based on the answers before? Does someone has a really short and basic example und how to get something like that running?

Sorry if that is a dumb question, but maybe someone has implemented already an example like that.

Anyway, thx for the help,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

> how could I achieve a ListView, showing only one item per page

with listview you can use change the scroll direction to horizontal

```
|-listView
  |-myfullscreenwidget which scrolls horizontally
```

> adds dynamically new questions based on the answers before

this is mainly a datasource question. you might want to ask this questions first

1. Is the data source local or online
2. Nature of questions, bool, multi-choice, short answer,
3. How to  validate response

finally  communicate with the database and push more questions to the list

Comment: Thx for the fast answer. So i have to manage the one item per screen in the displayed widget itself, right? Or is it better to do with ListView.separated()
Regarding the second question, I see that I probably have to start here first. Just creating some questions out of a source and push them into the list, then start putting a dynamic push and in the end getting response and the logic for the next question.
thx so far, maybe someone has some snippets how to start here :)